# Importação de arquivo .txt C++

Tags: c++

Quando eu faço a importação um espaço é adicionado no inicio do texto. 
exemplo: " A"
Como eu faço pra ignorar ele ?

```
Texto::Texto() {
    string pal, arquivoNome;
    char *palavra_aux;
    int i = 0;
    char *token = NULL;

    cout<<"Digite o nome do arquivo que contém o texto a ser corrigo, com a extensão: ";
    getline(cin,arquivoNome);

    ifstream arquivo(arquivoNome);
    pal.assign((istreambuf_iterator<char>(arquivo)),(istreambuf_iterator<char>())); // Tranfosma o conteudo do do arquivo para char

    palavra_aux = new char[pal.length()+1];
    strcpy(palavra_aux, pal.c_str());

    texto = palavra_aux;

    if (arquivo.is_open()) {

        token = strtok(palavra_aux," ,.;-? ");

        while (token != NULL) {
            palavra[i] = new Palavra(token);
            i++;
            token = strtok (NULL, " ,.;-? ");
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Falha ao abrir o arquivo!" << endl;
    }

    arquivo.close(); // Fecha arquivo
    tam = i;
}
```

Comment: onde o espaço aparece? no arquivo ou em uma string?

Comment: no vetor de string, surge um espaço q nem tem no arquivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema está nessas linhas

```
palavra_aux = new char[pal.length()+1];
strcpy(palavra_aux, pal.c_str());
```

Você cria o vetor de char com o tamanho da string + 1 e depois usa o **strcpy** que instanciará o tamanho da string para ocupar as ultimas posições do vetor, ou seja, preencherá as **pal.length()** posições do vetor e a que sobrou (no seu caso a primeira) ficará um lixo, que no seu caso está mostrando um espaço em branco.

```
palavra_aux = new char[pal.length()];
```

length já retorna o tamanho da string não a ultima posição.